# Can Drupal 8 security tables be modified?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to add another layer or field to the log-in of Drupal, is that possible?  Basically, I'd like to modify the Drupal security table to have that 1 field as part of the log-in credentials.  I've searched the documentations and haven't found any resources that points me to my questions.  I basically need to create a front-end app using Angular JS and will have an extra field for the log-in so not sure how to accomplish this.

I'd appreciate if you can point me to the right direction and what I need to do to get me started.  I sincerely appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: fields can be added at: `admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, the form display can be changed at `admin/config/people/accounts/form-display`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  It lets me add the fields, but not to the log-on screen.  Also, Can I modify the security table of Drupal to add that extra field?  It needs to be part of the logon credentials.  Any advice how to do this?  Thanks so much for your time and inputs.

Comment: You need to add a custom display for register at `admin/config/people/accounts/form-display` and add the fields you want to be on the register form. I don't know of any "security table"